# Orientation change and handle ConfingurationChanges manually in android

Tags: android, configuration, orientation

Here i develop one android application for both orientation Portrait and Landscape. So i create two layout folder for Landscape and Portrait and create two `layout.xml` files one for Portrait and second one is for landscape. In portrait `layout.xml` file has one ImageView and In Landscape `layout.xml` file has two ImageView. In `AndroidManifest.xml`, i set parameter `android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"` in `<activity>` entry to stop recreating activity on orientation changes. and In my Activity i override `onConfigurationChanges()` as below

```
 public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) 
 {
    try
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Toast.makeText(myContext, " Config Changed ", 1000).show();

        setContentView(R.layout.double_pageread_layout);

        setLayout();  // Initialize Controls (Buttons, ImageView,etc..)
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the Problem is that when i run my application. i can see it is perfect But When i change orientation it does not display anything.

Please Help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: the toast in this function never gets invoked ??

Comment: toast is every time invoked when orientation changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to manually change the layout by handling configuration changes. Simply place the two different `layout.xml` files into the `res/layout` and `res/layout-port` folders and Android will automatically inflate the proper one on rotate.